# Blazor onpointerenter event not firing

Tags: events, blazor, webassembly

.Net 5, Blazor (actual latest)

I would like to trigger an event when the pointer enters in an area.
For example:

```
<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px; background: red; pointer-events: all"
     @onpointerenter="@PointerEnter">
</div>

@code
{
    public void PointerEnter(PointerEventArgs args)
    {

    }
}
```

Whatever I do it isn't firing, although it is working with javascript.

(Mouse events are not an option, I want to use it with touch/pen inputs as well).

Can you tell me what am I missing and how can I make it work?

Comment: I confirm that it doesn't work, maybe it's a blazor bug?

Comment: Thanks, looks like yes. onpointerdown/onpointermove is working well.
+ I also try calling the element.releasePointerCapture() in js, but nothing works.